# Can not debug Adobe AIR mobile app on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I can not debug my simple Flex Mobile Project on my Samsung Galaxy S3. It is a default application with two empty views. Nothing more.

When I try to run the application it says:
"Adobe AIR is required on your device before deploying the projects to it. Would you like to install it now".

If I click "Yes" the launch stops on 57% and nothing happens.

The strange thing is that I have Adobe AIR installed on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

It will be a different version of AIR. What version are u compiling for?

Compile a `captive apk` to see if the App runs or is corrupted. Also for remote debugging I would reccomend using [Monster Debugger](http://www.demonsterdebugger.com/)